# GetOpt not working on Mac, none of the arguments show up

Tags: c++, macos, getopt

```
int c = 0; 
while (c = getopt(argc, argv, "p:t:e:") != -1) {
    std::cout<<"c: "<<c<<std::endl;
    switch (c) {
        case 'p':
            if (optarg) {
                std::cout << "lol" << std::endl;
                person = atoi(optarg);
            }
            break;
        case 't':
            if (optarg) {
                time = stod(optarg);
                std::cout << "ll" << std::endl;
            }
            break;
        case 'e':
            if (optarg) {
                ecg = atoi(optarg);
                std::cout << "2dasf" << std::endl;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Been trying to make getopt work on my Mac. C is printed as 1, but None of the print statements within the switch are printed. This works perfectly in Linux. What is wrong with my Mac?

Comment: So many checks of `if (optarg)`.. why don't you just check that *once* before the `switch`?

Comment: Aren't you assigning to c the result of comparing the option with -1? You should add parentheses to prevent that

Comment: @nsm I feel like an idoit. That was it